# Indexing JSON object in C++

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am looking to parse a JSON object much more efficiently than I am now. Currently I'm running through a range-based for loop to index the key-value elements (see below). Is it possible to run through all of the records inside of a JSON object and parse particular fields w/o a loop?

```
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
using json = nlohmann::json;

json myObj = json::parse(apiResponse);

for (auto& element : myObj.items()) {
    if (element.key() == "batters") {
        for (auto& element2 : element.value()) {
           std::cout << element2["batter"]["id"].get<std::string>() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of **one** JSON API response:

{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"batters":
{
"batter":
[
{ "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
]
},
}

{
"id": "0002",
"type": "donut",
"batters":
{
"batter":
[
{ "id": "2001", "type": "Lowfat" },
]
},
}

Thank you!
CookieCrisp

Comment: Nlohmann JSON values have a [find](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/find/) method similar to [std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) that's logarithmic in complexity instead of linear.

Comment: I'll have to try this. So could I do element.value.find("batter")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/at/ you can use the at()-method, which has a constant complexity when it's used with a location index parameter.

So for example you could do something like this:

```
std::cout << myObj.at(2)["batter"]["id"].get<std::string>() << std::endl;
```

Note that your JSON-fields must always be at the same position for this.
If that's not the case you could also use the field name as a key to find the field-object you need.
But then you will have logarithmic complexity.

```
std::cout << myObj.at("batters")["batter"]["id"].get<std::string>() << std::endl;
```